# Retrieve File Size in Android programmatically

Tags: android, file, uri

I'm looking for a way to read 'PDF' size. so far I have attempted the following approaches:

**Note:** all the permissions are in place and i do have access to the file.

**1) using file length**

```
path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/c4611_sample_explain.pdf";
File file = new File(path);
int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length() / 1024));
```

**RESULT :**
It works on images, but returns 0 on pdf files

**2) using cursor**

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
String size= "null";
if (cursor != null) {
    size=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE));
    cursor.close();
}
```

**RESULT :**

```
size: null 
path: /storage/emulated/0/Download/c4611_sample_explain.pdf 
URI: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/c4611_sample_explain.pdf

UPDATE: Cursor returns null
```

Is there something else I should do ?

Comment: You are not calling `cursor.moveToFirst();` before reading value from `cursor`

Comment: @Sagar I suspect it is more of null cursor issue. is there something wrong with using URI the way im using it ? `file://` if so how can i get `content://`

Comment: You can debug and check if its null. I think URI is fine. Before we dig into URI just ensure existing code works

Comment: yes I have checked the `contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)` returns null

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length() /` ?? Pretty strange you convert an integer to a String. Please try again.

Comment: `all the permissions are in place` ?? Which ones? And confirmed by the user at runtime? On wich Android version?

Comment: @greenapps READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I've tested it on API 26

Comment: Repeat: `And confirmed by the user at runtime? On wich Android version?`. Version please. I dont know all those sdk numbers. And did you remove the String already?

Comment: @greenapps yes confirmed by user at runtime. API26 is Oreo 8.0

Comment: Remove the String. And if you post such a problem then just tell what file.length() delivers. No calculations please. Also use file.exists() before you handle the file.

Comment: What is your minimum support?, if it is 26 and above then you can try this `sizeInBytes = Files.size(path);`

Answer (score 2):

It seams that you are using the schemes wrong, on your "using cursor" result you posted:

```
URI: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/c4611_sample_explain.pdf
```

If you see the URI starts with "file:" but using the cursor approach, the URI must start with "content:"

First you need to check the scheme, if it is "file" or "content", then you obtain the file size. I hope this code helps:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    Uri filePath = data.getData();
    if (data.getData().getScheme().equals("file")) {
        File file = new File(filePath.toString());
        int fileSize = (int) file.length();
        System.out.println("This is the file size: " + fileSize);
    } else if (data.getData().getScheme().equals("content")) {
        Cursor returnCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(filePath, null, null, null, null);
        assert returnCursor != null;
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String fileSize = returnCursor.getString(sizeIndex);
        System.out.println("This is the file size: " + fileSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your if statement to:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() )
```

and also add a projection to your query method:

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE };
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Comment: the problem is. the cursor itself returns null

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method

method to format the size of a file

```
public static String formatSize(long size) {
    String suffix = null;

    if (size >= 1024) {
        suffix = " Bytes";
        size /= 1024;
        if (size >= 1024) {
            suffix = " MB";
            size /= 1024;
        }
    }
    StringBuilder resultBuffer = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(size));

    int commaOffset = resultBuffer.length() - 3;
    while (commaOffset > 0) {
        resultBuffer.insert(commaOffset, ',');
        commaOffset -= 3;
    }
    if (suffix != null) resultBuffer.append(suffix);
    return resultBuffer.toString();
}
```

And read the file from your storage

```
 String pathname= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 String fullpath= pathname + "/dummy2.pdf";
 File file=new File(fullpath);
 String size = formatSize(file.length());// this will give you the size of the file
```

Hope it helps you.

Happy Coding ;)